# Alamofire + SwiftyJSON Compile Error after converting to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

This line has always been working fine for me for making Alamofire Requests and getting the JSON response.

```
Alamofire.request(req).responseJSON() {
        (request, response, data, error) in

    // ....

}
```

After upgrading to XCode 7 and converting the Project to Swift 2.0, all the lines of code that have my Alamofire request are not showing this error:

```
'(_, _, _, _) -> Void' is not convertible to 'Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void'
```

Comment: I'm confused, but the Alamofire doc says that's how it should be called.  Even when I took it down to 2 params, still the same error, except it shows (_,_) instead of (_,_,_,_)

Comment: Added an answer below, had to open up an AF project in Xcode7 to see, hope it works!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the answer in this [link](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/16844/alamofire-3-0%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6json%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95) but it is in japanese. It seems this is the correct from now (taken from answer in link):

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, requestUrl).responseJSON {
   response in
    if response.result.isSuccess {
        let jsonDic = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
        let responseData = jsonDic["responseData"] as! NSDictionary
        self.newsDataArray = responseData["results"] as! NSArray
        self.table.reloadData()
    }            
}
```

Comment: I am trying this right now.  So far, this is removing my compile errors.  I need to do this a few more times in various areas before I can build my app to test, then I'll let you know the results.

Comment: You saved me, this seems to be the correct answer.  In short, this is now working for me.  Still quite a few tweaks I need to do based on this new form, but I can see my log statements pulling results.

Comment: It seems that if you install Alamofire using Cocoapods, this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: Unless you follow the project closely, I'd suggest you roll back to the Alamofire 2.0.2 release until we have a chance to update the documentation and create a migration guide for the Alamofire 3.0.0-beta.1 changes.

Comment: Thanks! The error handling is the key part that this adds that doesn't seem to be covered in the Alamofire 3 migration guide - lots of examples of getting data, but no examples of how error handling is intended to be done. @cnoon Would be nice to have the guide or documentation updated to include some more practical examples, not just printing results.

Answer (score 2):

Old syntax:

```
Alamofire.request(req).responseJSON() {
  (request, response, data, error) in
   // ....
}
```

New syntax:

```
Alamofire.request(req).responseJSON() {
  response in
  if response.result.isSuccess {
    let data = response.result.value
    // ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I pulled up a project with AF and here you go:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, someRequest).responseJSON { (request, response, result) -> Void in


    }
```

Looks like it's just 3 parameters for the closure, request, response & the result object. I'd imagine this is because this should be something that throws in Swift 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Alamofire-SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON) the error handling is the same:

```
.responseSwiftyJSON({ (request, response, json, error) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        print("Received error \(error)")
        return
    }
    else {
        print("Received json response \(json)")
    }
}
```

but now `error` is a `ErrorType` instead of a `NSError`.

Using plain Alamofire and iOS JSON, the response and error are unified in a result of type `Result<AnyObject>`, you have to unwrap the result:

```
.responseJSON { request, response, result in
    switch result {
    case .Success(let value):
        print("Received response \(value)")
    case .Failure(_, let error):
        print("Received error \(error)")
    }
```